# Why does this work? (HTML+PHP)

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me why this works?

```
<?php if ($selected_subject_id) { ?>
    <h2>Manage Subject</h2>
<?php } elseif ($selected_page_id) { ?>
    <h2>Manage Page</h2>
<?php } else { ?>
    Please select a subject or a page.
<?php }?>
```

Basically,
if you click a subject "Manage Subject" displays as title
if you click a page "Manage Page" displays as title
if neither are clicked it displays "Please select a subject or page"
ONLY ONE OF THESE ARE DISPLAYED AT A TIME

My question is, why do the titles/msg behave as if they were inside the PHP script (obeying the conditionals) when they are actually outside of it?

Is it because they're "within" the opening and closing braces of the conditional?

In what other situations will this work?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Is it because they're "within" the opening and closing braces of the conditional?"* ~ yes. See also http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: The simplest way to understand it is to treat everything "outside" the `<?php ... ?>` script as if it's a big `echo` statement with the text as a literal string. But nothing is interpreted within it: there's no variable expansion, no escape sequences, etc.

Comment: read this:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it

Answer (score 0):

PHP is indeed able to conditionally echo HTML in this manner. This is actually used quite commonly.

You can also echo HTML in a loop.

Comment: but echoing html is not a good idea,what ever he is doing is correct.

Comment: I meant 'echo' as in print in this manner, not as in the `echo` keyword.